# My 18 yo son inherited his grandmother's house and his father wants to buy it for $1

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, pennsylvania

My 18-year-old son inherited his grandmother's house. His father wants to buy it from him for $1.  Wouldn't my son have to pay capital gains tax? The house is in Pennsylvania

Comment: How would it be in your son's best interests to give away his inheritance like this? Assuming dad's good intentions (?), there is surely a better way of achieving whatever he's trying to do.

Comment: Apart from the taxes, it's likely to wreck your father's relationship with his son, if he forces him to give away a house that would presumably help keep him financially secure for life. Your husband should consider that before attempting to force the issue.

Comment: @DStanley she(?) seems to mean that the father wants "him" the son to sell it to "him" the father for $1.

Comment: From the little you've told us, this sounds a whole lot like the father is trying to scam the house from his son.  More details would help.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon just because a man is the father of this woman's son, you can't assume that she is married to him. :/

Comment: @NathanL You are very right - bad assumption. I also accidentally referred to the father as "your [the op's] father", which proves a much more grievous editing error on my part!

Comment: @Nathan L: These days, you can't even assume that the OP is a woman :-)

Comment: @jamesqf it is 95% of the time...

Comment: There's some "folk wisdom" in PA that a $1 recorded deed escapes the PA real estate transfer tax, and you'll certainly see $1 value in a lot of county real estate records for last sale price.  However, transfers between certain family members are already a statutory exemption.  http://www.revenue.pa.gov/GeneralTaxInformation/Tax%20Types%20and%20Information/Pages/Realty-Transfer-Tax.aspx#.WfjMh1tSxEY

Answer (score 5):

Inherited real estate is purchased at a "stepped up" basis.  That is for tax purposes the house price is the value at the time of death.  So grandma might have bought the house for $20, and the time of her death, if it is worth 550K the basis price is 550k for your son.

If your son sells the house for $1, then that advantage will be lost.  There could be a tax liability created when there does not have to be one.  The father when he goes to sell the house could have to pay taxes on the difference between $1 and the current value.  A pretty dumb move.

A better option would be for your son to rent the home to his father.  He could do so for the carrying cost:  taxes, and insurance and that should be acceptable by all.

Comment: Why would the son owe taxes on the sale? He got the stepped up basis.

Comment: Say what? He inherited the house, basis stepped up. If he sells it for less than that value, how does he owe any tax?

Comment: Selling a house for $1 is a gift to the purchaser, and gifts can be taxable to the giver.

Comment: Yes. Your answer feels right. But basis usually follows a gift. Seems strange a dollar transaction would both make this a gift, subject to potential gift tax to giver, as well as a dollar basis. Either way, it seems a potential mess.